# extract .bin files

Tags: file, extract, bin

So I have an old dictionary on my pc, pretty old that I cannot find
any track of it's developer or the website (I guess it hasnt even been released
as an official software). I have a personal project of mine and I might need some
of this words translated (about 200-300) and I see that inside the data folder that
contains the database/list of files but Im unable to extract or read this files.
Is there any way to extract or convert these .bin files to a text format or something
readable. I've used some tools like (alcohol 120%, isobuster, magiciso, Izarc) but with
no luck. I keep getting and error message saying it is not a valid cd image file.

So I'm thinking maybe this type of .bin files are not like .bin or .iso cd files that
you can mount and read and something else might be in this case.

If you have any information kindly reply with
your suggestions.

Thank you alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the strings utility to extract the strings out of the file. It comes with any Linux distribution and if you are on Windows, you can get it from [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx).

If you are lucky and the words are not encoded, you may be able to get at the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but can you please send me a link to the exact tool, cause I dont know what tool to download at the link you sent me.

Answer (score 0):

`.bin` is one of those extensions that has been way overused, and could be anything... What did the file come from originally? Do you need to convert these words and store them back in the original file (in their transformed form), and then expect the original app to work correctly?

Comment: Hello. This is part of a small (technical) dictionary. So inside the data folders there are about 4 .bin files  and I judge these are the
application "database" that contain all the words.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm getting at - unless you know what the application is, and the original authors actually documented the format of those files, the best option you have is a reverse-engineering effort... However if you just need to extract the information, that's fairly easy to do, as mentioned in some other answers/comments. Getting the transformed data back into those files in a way that makes sense, though, requires that you know what "makes sense" to whatever uses those files.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond. I'm not a desktop programmer and have no much knowledge about this.Is there any reference tutorial you can show me? thank you alot for your efforts so far